# How to create nice bottom-border fadeIn on hover?

Tags: jquery

I want something like *[this website](https://deuxhuithuit.com/en/)* has when you hover over the navigation bar's items.

I personally made the bottom-borders appear on hover, but the animation is not that nice.

Comment: What is it that you've tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `transition` property:

```
.your_element {
  transition: border-bottom 2s ease;
  border-bottom: solid 1px transparent;
}

.your_element:hover {
   border-bottom: solid 1px #000;
}
```

Also take a look at: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/

Comment: can someone explain the -1?